# If a rational function has no horizontal asymptote, does it then have to have a slant asymptote

Tags: graphing-functions, rational-functions

This is assuming that the function is in a fractional form where the the degree of the numerator is higher than the degree of the denominator.

Comment: $\displaystyle\,\frac{x^2}{1}\,$ is a rational function. Does it have an asymptote?

Comment: No it doesn't, sorry I didn't specify my answer, I will update it

Comment: A polynomial P(x) does not.  P(x) + $\frac 1{Q(x)}$ where $Q(x)$ is a polynomial where $\lim Q(x) = 0$ will not.  So no does not appear that it must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=P(x)/Q(x)$ be a rational function, where $P$ and $Q$ are nonzero polynomials; then

- $f$ has a horizontal asymptote if and only if $\deg P\le\deg Q$
- $f$ has an oblique asymptote if and only if $\deg P=1+\deg Q$

*Proof.* We can write $P(x)=A(x)Q(x)+R(x)$, where $\deg R<\deg Q$ (or $R(x)$ is the zero polynomial). Thus
$$
f(x)=A(x)+\frac{R(x)}{Q(x)}
$$
Clearly
$$
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{R(x)}{Q(x)}=0
$$
Thus, if $\deg A(x)>0$ (that is, $\deg P>\deg Q$), $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=\pm\infty$ (with suitable choices of sign in the limit). If $A(x)=c$ is constant, then
$$
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)=c
$$
and so $f$ has a horizontal asymptote. This is the same as saying that $\deg P\le\deg Q$.

Suppose $\deg P=1+\deg Q$; then $A(x)=ax+b$, with $a\ne0$. Then
$$
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=a
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}(f(x)-ax)=b
$$
If $\deg P>1+\deg Q$, then
$$
\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\pm\infty
$$
(again with suitable choices of signs in the limit) and $f$ has no oblique asymptote.

Answer (score 0):

No, a slant asymptote occurs when the numerator has a degree exactly one unit higher than the denominator. If the difference between degrees is greater, then there cnb be only vertical asymptotes.

Comment: Technically speaking, in higher degrees, there is asymptotic behavior to a function (which is not an asymptote, but still). For example $\frac{x^4+1}{x^2}$ has an asymptotic relationship to $x^2$

Comment: I think that OP means straight asymptotes.